# How to update Cucumber-JVM's --format option?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

My Cucumber feature looks like this:
Feature: Login Action

```
Scenario: Successful Login with Valid Credentials
Given User is on Home Page
When User Navigate to LogIn Page
And User enters UserName and Password
Then Message displayed Login Successfully

Scenario: Successful LogOut
When User LogOut from the Application
Then Message displayed LogOut Successfully
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> WARNING: Cucumber-JVM's --format option is deprecated. Please use
>   --plugin instead. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory:
>   C:\Users\testjack001\workspace\myProject\src\myFeature.feature    at
>   cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterator$FileIterator.(FileResourceIterator.java:54)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterator.(FileResourceIterator.java:20)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterable.iterator(FileResourceIterable.java:19)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.loadFromFeaturePath(CucumberFeature.java:101)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:54)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:34)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(RuntimeOptions.java:201)
>     at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:109)   at
>   cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)   at
>   cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)

How can I get this issue resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry regarding the --format option is just a warning, it is not an error. Your error starts in the next line:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: C:\Users\testjack001\workspace\myProject\src\myFeature.feature

Cucumber can not find your feature file at the location it expects it to be placed.

Comment: However, I would like to know how to get rid of the warning displayed? WARNING: Cucumber-JVM's --format option is deprecated. Please use --plugin instead.
Can you suggest some idea ?

Comment: How are you setting up Cucumber, can you add the java code or the configuration to your initial post?

Comment: I sometimes dont even get the missing functions when I run my feature file. Any ideas?

Comment: Please open up a new question for this, as it might be a completely different topic.

Comment: I know its too late. But, yes thi has worked for me already. Marking this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Update your pom.xml dependencies to cucumber version 1.2.3

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```